# How do I limit the number of concurrent processes spawned by Proc::Async in Perl 6?

Tags: asynchronous, raku

I want to process a list of files in a subtask in my script and I'm using `Proc::Async` to spawn the subprocesses doing the work. The downside is that if I have a large list of files to process, it will spawn many subprocesses. I want to know how to limit the number of concurrent subprocesses that `Proc::Async` spawns?

Comment: Perhaps what you want is [`hyper`](http://doc.perl6.org/type/Iterable#method_hyper) or [`race`](http://doc.perl6.org/type/Iterable#method_race)? Please show some demo code so that we have a better idea how best to answer your question.

Comment: Have you seen [Parallelism, Concurrency, and Asynchrony in Perl 6 by Jonathan Worthington](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JpqnNCx7wVY)?

Comment: Extending @ChristopherBottoms comments: it sounds like what you want is task parallelism, not (or perhaps as well as) asynchrony; a straight read through the first 28 or perhaps 38 of the [Parallelism, Concurrency, and Asynchrony in Perl 6 slides](http://jnthn.net/papers/2015-spw-concurrency.pdf) might do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can explicitly limit the number of `Proc::Async` processes using this react block technique which Jonathan Worthington demonstrated in [his concurrency/parallelism/asynchrony talk at the 2019 German Perl Workshop](http://jnthn.net/papers/2019-gpw-react-supply-whenever.pdf) (see slide 39, for example). I'm using the Linux command `echo N` as my "external process" in the code below.

```
#!/bin/env perl6    
my @items = <foo bar baz>;

for @items -> $item {
    start { say "Planning on processing $item" }
}

# Run 2 processes at a time
my $degree = 2;

react {
    # Start $degree processes at first
    run-one-process for 1..$degree;

    # Run one, run-one again when it ends, thus maintaining $degree active processes at a time
    sub run-one-process {
        my $item    = @items.shift // return;
        my $proc    = Proc::Async.new('echo', "processing $item");
        my @output;

        # Capture output
        whenever $proc.stdout.lines { push @output, $_; }

        # Print all the output, then start the next process
        whenever $proc.start {
            @output.join("\n").say;
            run-one-process
        }
    }
}
```

---

Old Answer:

Based on Jonathan Worthington's talk *Parallelism, Concurrency, and Asynchrony in Perl 6* ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JpqnNCx7wVY), [slides](http://jnthn.net/papers/2015-spw-concurrency.pdf)), this sounds most like ***parallelism*** (i.e. choosing to do multiple things at once; see slide 18). ***Asynchrony*** is reacting to things in the future, the timing of which we cannot control; see slides 39 and 40. As @raiph pointed out in his comment you can have one, the other, or both.

If you care about the order of results, then use [`hyper`](http://doc.perl6.org/type/Iterable#method_hyper), but if the order isn't important, then use [`race`](http://doc.perl6.org/type/Iterable#method_race).

In this example, adapted from [Jonathan Worthington's slides](http://jnthn.net/papers/2015-spw-concurrency.pdf), you build a pipeline of steps in which data is processed in batches of 32 filenames using 4 workers:

```
sub MAIN($data-dir) {
    my $filenames = dir($data-dir).race(batch => 32, degree => 4);
    my $data = $filenames.map(&slurp);
    my $parsed = $data.map(&parse-climate-data);
    my $european = $parsed.grep(*.continent eq 'Europe');
    my $max = $european.max(by => *.average-temp);
    say "$max.place() is the hottest!";
}
```